# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'classlist.js' in angular cli 6.1.3

Tags: angular

I am getting following while running `ng buid --watch` command in terminal,

```
ERROR in ./src/polyfills.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'classlist.js' in 'E:\eclipse_dis_workspace\tourdubai\UI\src'
```

following version used,

```
Angular CLI: 6.1.3
Node: 8.11.3
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 6.1.2
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.7.3
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.7.5
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.7.5
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.7.5
@angular-devkit/core              0.7.3
@angular-devkit/schematics        0.7.3
@angular/cli                      6.1.3
@ngtools/webpack                  6.1.5
@schematics/angular               0.7.3
@schematics/update                0.7.3
rxjs                              6.2.2
typescript                        2.7.2
webpack                           4.9.2
```

i did all the setup configuration, like npm i.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

remove the current package

```
npm uninstall classlist.js --save
```

then run

```
npm cache verify
```

run

```
npm install classlist.js --save-exact
```

Comment: thanks for replay. after this compiled successfully but in browser console following error : showing Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined,

Comment: @Balasubramanian: That sounds like an Angular Version compatibility problem; but you scaffolded the project from Scratch, right?

Comment: remove the *node_modules* folder manually, then run `npm cache clean --force` then run `npm install`

Comment: @DieWebagenten not scratch but maybe angular version problem. so how can i fix this?

Comment: @Balasubramanian: Different options; I would suggest 1. Add (window as any).global = window; in polyfills.ts; if that doesn´t work, then 2. Add <script>
var global = global || window;
var Buffer = Buffer || [];
var process = process || {
  env: { DEBUG: undefined },
  version: []
};
</script>  to Index.html. Either of them should work

Answer (score 0):

There are different options;

I would suggest to add

```
(window as any).global = window;
```

in polyfills.ts;

if that doesn´t work, then add

```
<script>
var global = global || window;
var Buffer = Buffer || [];
var process = process || {
env: { DEBUG: undefined },
version: []
};
</script>
```

to Index.html; either of them should work.